# Using R : linear model (lm) - Fixed Effect Model - Vary intercept by different factor than the coefficient

Tags: r, regression, formula, lm

I am having a problem setting up a panel data model (Fixed Effects) in R.

Currently I am running the following code:

```
fe1 <- summary(lm(qnorm(y) ~ factor(Bank) -1  + factor(Country)*x ,data=PDwideHPI))
```

Each Bank has 6 observations per country. **I would expect that the summary output would provide me with a bank-specific intercept and secondly, a country specific coefficient for x. However, the R console returns bank-specific AND country-specific intercepts.**

Thus I receive estimates for: `Factor(Bank)1 Factor(Bank)2 Factor(Bank)3 Factor(Bank)4 Factor(Country)1 Factor(Country)2 x Factor(Country)1:x Factor(Country)2:x`

whereas I expect the following: `Factor(Bank)1 Factor(Bank)2 Factor(Bank)3 Factor(Bank)4 x Factor(Country)1:x Factor(Country)2:x`

How do I solve this?

Comment: Making your example [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) would go a long way towards making it easier to help you. If you include sample data, it's easier to see what's going on. Perhaps you want `factor(Country):x` rather than `factor(Country)*x` in your formula. The former includes the non-interaction terms as well.

Comment: Yes will do the next time! Your solution works perfectly by the way, that was what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: To make your code clearer and more legible, convert `Bank` and `Country` to factors when/immediately after you read them in. e.g. use `as.factor()` or  `read.csv(... colClasses)`. Then your formula terms will simply be called `Bank<n>`, `Country<n>` without the `Factor(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the default R formula syntax the `*` not only includes the interaction terms, but also includes the individual terms. If you just want the interaction term, then you the `:` operator. So you in your case, you want

```
fe1 <- summary(lm(qnorm(y) ~ factor(Bank) -1  + factor(Country):x ,data=PDwideHPI))
```